# Google Earth won't display a path from a QGIS KML file

Tags: qgis, kml, display

A friend created a KML file(s) for a special bike ride project.  He included a path.  Several operators were using this file in Google Earth.  One however could see everything in the file, mile markers, hospitals, rest stops, etc. but NOT the path.

It appears that this behavior is limited to one specific laptop.  Four others did not have this problem.

Comment: What are the differences to the other laptop?

Comment: can you provide the kml file?

Answer (score 1):

You could try unchecking the Terrain option in the layers panel, as it's shown in the figure below:[image]